continuity of map of distances
Assume $X$ is a compact metric space and $Y$ is a metric space, where $X$ and $Y$ are both connected. Assume $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous. Define the map $g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=d(f(x),Y\backslash f(B_{r}(x))$. Is this map continuous? Assuming $f(B_r(x))\neq Y$ for no $x$
Due to comments, above imply here f will be surjective.
If $f(B_r(x))=F$ for all $x$ ($F$ is independent of $x$) then it is easy.
Let. $x_n$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$. $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$.
$|g(x)-g(x_n)|=|d(f(x),Y\backslash f(B_r(x))-d(f(x_n),Y\backslash f(B_r(x_n)|$
How would one bound this? What if $f(B_r(x))$ is an open set for all $x$?
When will it be continuous?

$f(B_r(x))$ being open for all $x$ would imply $f(X)$ is open as $X$ is a union of $r$-balls. But $X$ is compact, so $f(X)$ is closed, thus clopen. But you’re assuming $Y$ is connected, so $f$ would have to be surjective in that case.

Is $r$ fixed (and $> 0$)?

@ronno yes. That is correct

Note that your function $g$ can take infinite value if $f(B_r(x))=Y$ for some $x$. If you allow this, then continuity fails even in the case when $f$ is the identity map.

@monoidaltransform Do you insist on a given $r$ or may I choose one? Do you insist on  $f(B_r(x))\neq Y$ AND the surjectivity of $f$ or may I choose $f$ with $f(X)\neq Y$?

@MariusS.L. id like to know the answer for both

@monoidaltransform Topology is the area of mathematics where I'd rather look for a counterexample than a proof. But unless you specify the conditions (properties of $f$, whether the topologies have to be induced by the metrics, quantifier of $r$, order of the quantifier, esp. the dependency on $x$, etc.), it does not make sense to try. It will ultimately be a waste of time since you could always invent new conditions. I have an idea, but I cannot adjust my example to unknown conditions.

@MariusS.L. im mainly interested in case of $f(X)\neq Y$.

You should revise your question by editing its body instead of commenting. At this point, your question is unclear and the body of the question contradicts your comments. Also, in the sentence "Assuming (())≠ for no " I think you mean opposite of what you wrote.

I assume you really mean that for all $x\in X$, $f(B_r(x))\ne Y$. (You wrote that "$f(B_r(x))\ne Y$ for no $x\in X$" which means that $f(B_r(x))=Y$ for all $x\in X$.)
Here is an example with discontinuous function $g$:
Let $X=[-1,1]$, $Y=[-1,2]$ be intervals in $\mathbb R$ equipped with the standard metric. Consider the function
$$\
f(x)=\begin{cases} x & \hbox{if}\ x\le 0 \\
2x & \hbox{if}\ x\ge 0
\end{cases} 
$$
It defines a homeomorphism $X\to Y$. Then for $r=1$ the function $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ since
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} g\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)=2, \ g(0)=1. 
$$
In general, $g$ is lower semicontinuous (assuming that $f$ is an open map).

My counterexample where I used the fact that the subspace topology of the unit interval $Y$ allows a "discontinuity" that the unit circle $X$ does not have.
Let
$$
X = \left\{\underbrace{(\cos(t),\sin(t))}_{=\gamma(t)}\in \mathbb{R}^2\, : \,0\leq t \leq 2\pi \right\}
$$
be the (compact and metric) unit circle with the subspace topology, parameterized by the angle $\gamma\, : \,[0,2\pi]\rightarrow X.$ We define
$$
Y=\left\{ \{[0,c]\}\, : \, 0\leq c \leq2\pi\right\}
$$
where each point is an interval starting at $0$, and endow it with the French railway metric
$$
d(\{[0,c_1]\},\{[0,c_2]\})= \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if }c_1=c_2\\ c_1+c_2&\text{if }c_1\neq c_2\,.
\end{cases} 
$$
$Y$ is path connected,
$$
t\cdot \{[0,c_2]\}+(1-t)\cdot \{[0,c_1]\}=\{[0,tc_2+(1-t)c_1]\},
$$
and therefore connected. We define $f\, : \,X\rightarrow Y$ as
$$
f(\gamma(t))=\left\{\left[0, t\right]\right\}
$$
which is continuous according to the subspace topology of the real line which $Y$ is homeomorphic to, or according to the topology induced by the metric. Furthermore, we can determine whether $f$ is surjective or not simply by allowing larger intervals in $Y$ or compressing the image intervals of $f.$
The closed balls $B_r(x)\subseteq X$ are circle segments of arc length $2r$ with center $x\in X.$ We are interested in what happens around $x=(1,0)$ so we consider $B_{\pi/4}(1,0)=B_{\pi/4}(\gamma(0))$ and
\begin{align*}
f\left(B_{\pi/4}(1,0)\right)&=f\left(\left\{\gamma(t): t\in [7\pi/4,2\pi]\cup [0,\pi/4] \right\}\right)\\
&=\bigcup_{t\in [7\pi/4,2\pi]}\left\{[0,t]\right\}
\cup \bigcup_{t\in [0,\pi/4]}\left\{[0,t]\right\}\\
Y\backslash f\left(B_{\pi/4}(1)\right)&=\bigcup_{t\in (\pi/4,7\pi/4)}\left\{[0,t]\right\}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
g(x_0)&=d\left(f(\gamma(t_0)),\bigcup_{t\in (\pi/4,7\pi/4)}\left\{[0,t]\right\}\right)\\
&=d\left(\left\{\left[0, t_0\right]\right\},\left\{\left\{\left[0, t\right]\right\}:\pi/4<t<7\pi/4\right\}\right)\\
&=\inf\left\{t_0+t\, : \,\pi/4<t<7\pi/4\right\}\\
&=t_0+\pi/4 
\end{align*}
Hence, we have
$$
\lim_{x_0 \searrow (1,0)}g(x_0)=\lim_{t_0 \to 0}g(\gamma(t_0))=\lim_{t_0 \to 0}\left(t_0+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x_0 \nearrow (1,0)}g(x_0)=\lim_{t_0 \to 2\pi}g(\gamma(t_0))=\lim_{t_0 \to 2\pi}\left(t_0+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=\dfrac{9}{4}\pi\,.
$$
